# Is ColdFusion evaluate() really dangerous?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Upon reading https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3429940 (is PHP `eval()` really dangerous?)

And http://dhorrigan.com/post/30395987906/is-eval-really-evil-yes-and-no

I am wondering if the ColdFusion equivalent has similar issues.

Comment: There's almost no reason to ever use evaluate. Scope your variables.

Comment: I suggest trying it with some benign code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the warnings on the PHP function are histrionic & a bit facile, because they focus on one specific misuse of the construct, rather than its general purpose.

`evaluate()` will be less prone to this because it cannot execute any amount of code, it can simply evaluate individual expressions (albeit more than one, separately and disconnectedly executed).

The thing is - and this is touched on in the PHP articles too - it's just seldom, if ever, needed. If you find yourself using it... you're probably doing something wrong.

For further reading, I discuss this on my blog: ["`evalulate()` is really slow". Is it now?](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/08/evalulate-is-really-slow-is-it-now.html)

Comment: The link has the best explanation of `evaluate()` I have ever seen.

Comment: (Edit) *cannot execute any amount of code* I do not think that is completely true. Depending on how `evaluate` is used, a well crafted post could get it to execute *some* amount of code, or at the very least leak information about the application. (Ignoring the fact that it is rarely needed anyway..) that alone is reason to avoid it, IMO.

Comment: ... and yes I understand "...it can simply evaluate individual expressions" does mitigate *some* of the risks, but not enough to dismiss it IMO. Not implying that *you* are dismissing it .. but I rarely see discussions about that aspect of evaluate. (Usually just a lot of back and forth about the old "performance" argument).