# Coldfusion alternative to evaluate() due to possible code injection?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Currently just finishing up a code review and the auditor doesn't like this use of `evaluate()` and assigns it a high risk due to possible code injection.

The user is presented a form of products associated with his or her account.  There's a hidden input with a `valuelist` of the product IDs.  There are then radio inputs to change the status of products. There could be anywhere from 1 to several products listed. Those inputs are all named `r_#productid#`:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="prodIdList" value="#valueList(prodIds)#"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#pr_prid#" name="r_#pr_prid#" value="X" checked="checked"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#pr_prid#" name="r_#pr_prid#" value="P"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#pr_prid#" name="r_#pr_prid#" value="L"/>
</form>
```

When submitted the code loops over the form.prodIdList and evalutes those IDs to get the submitted value (X, P or L).

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(FORM,"doProcessChanges")>
  <cfloop list="#FORM.assetIdList#" index="i">
    <cfswitch expression="#Evaluate('FORM.r_' & i)#">
      <cfcase value="P">
        --- do something i=productId ---
      </cfcase>
      <cfcase value="L">
        --- do something else i=productId  ---  
      </cfcase>
    </cfswitch> 
  </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Is there an alternate way of accomplishing this that doesn't use Evaluate and will satisfy this code reviewer?

[edit] One change I did was to evaluate and then check the values vs. an expected list or regex.  I hadn't thought of array notation and will give that a try as well.  For now here's the first update:

```
gender = evaluate('form.gender_' & i);
    if( gender == 'M' || gender == 'F' || gender == 'O' || gender == 'X' ) {
    -- do stuff
    } else {
    -- error 
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Variable Naming and Reference (ColdFusion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410726/dynamic-variable-naming-and-reference-coldfusion)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075509/trying-to-replace-all-evaluate-functions-with-dynamic-notation-in-coldfusion-9

Comment: Btw, most all system scopes like FORM, URL, etc.. are structures, so you can always use associative array notation to access keys dynamically, ie <cfset theValue = scopeName["staticName" & dynamicIndex]>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ColdFusion evaluate() really dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179728/is-coldfusion-evaluate-really-dangerous)

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion?

Comment: @JamesAMohler - CF2016.  Whether it's really dangerous or not isn't really up to me.  The company doing the code audit doesn't like it as it is so I have to change it.  See edits above for changes that I implemented.

Comment: One suggestion about the "edit" code, when comparing many values, it is shorter to use listFind() or listFindNoCase() rather than many OR conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array notation like this `FORM['r_' & i]` instead of `Evaluate('FORM.r_' & i)`. I think this is a duplicate question. I'll flag if I can find the original.

Comment: You have an extra ' up there.  I ended up going with this solution:  gender = FORM['gender_' & i];

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that can be done to make this code safer is to use `encodeForHTMLAttribute()`

Furthermore, it should be scoped to whatever generated it. I image a query created this, so a query's name should be used

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="prodIdList" value="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(valueList(qry.prodIds))#"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" name="r_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" value="X" checked="checked"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" name="r_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" value="P"/>
   <input type="radio" id="dn_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" name="r_#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(qry.pr_prid)#" value="L"/>
</form>
```